# xsd annotation with JWS

Tags: java, soap

I'm required to provide documentation in my XSD files for a web service I'm making. How can I by using Java Annotations ensure the following XML in my XSD file? I'm using JWS.

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Some documentation here</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a good way to go was the "Contract first" method. I copied the generated wsdl and xsd files into WEB-INF/wsdl and specified wsdlLocation in the WebService annotation. Then I added the xml (specified in the original question) to the xsd files.